# Is it possible to launch an AWS marketplace AMI to an existing instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dataset, amazon-ami, amazon-marketplace

I have an g3.xlarge instance which my data set is there and I wanted to install DIGITS but it didn't work unfortunately.

I am in rush to classify my data so decided to use marketplace instead of dealing with installation problems.

Now my question is that is there any way that I can use DIGITS marketplace in my existing instance since I don't want to waste time again to upload my data to new instance again. My data set is really big (1,322,000 images). Please help me it is my first time using AWS.

Comment: It sounds like your best bet would be for that big data set to be in S3 so that it isn't directly tied to an EC2 instance.  That way you could spin up potentially many instances to work on the data set.  Either way, no, the AMI is an entire machine image and you can't apply it to an existing instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NVIDIA DIGITS from the Marketplace without having to upload your data again. You need to create a new NVIDIA DIGITS instance, create a snapshot of the volume of your primary g3.xlarge instance, create a new volume with this snap, attach this new volume to the new NVIDIA DIGITS instance and mount this new volume.

Here are the steps to do that:

- Go to the AWS EC2 console
- Create a new NVIDIA DIGITS instance
- Choose Volumes on the left
- Select the volume corresponding to your g3.xlarge instance, and create a Snapshot (if you have several volumes, choose the volume that contains your data)
- Choose Snapshots on the left
- Select your new snapshot
- Select "Action / Create volume" and give a new name to this new volume, that is a copy of the snap.
- Choose Snapshots on the left and remove the snapshot (now that you have a new volume that is the copy of the original one, there is no more need to use the snapshot)
- Choose Volumes on the left, select the new volume and select "Action / Attach volume" to attach your copy of the original volume to your new NVIDIA DIGITS instance.
- mount the new volume (use dmesg to see the new virtual hardware and then use mount to mount it, for instance on /mnt/mydata)